# Powershell - Empty entries in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, output

I don't have much experience with CSV, so apologies if I'm really blind here.

I have a basic CSV and script setup to test this with. The CSV has two columns, Letter and Number. Letter goes from A-F and Number goes from 1-10. This means that Number has more rows than Letter, so when running the following script, the output can sometimes provide an empty Letter.

```
$L = ipcsv ln.csv | Get-Random | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Letter
$N = ipcsv ln.csv | Get-Random | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Number

Write-Output $L
Write-Output $N
```

Some outputs come out as

```
B
9
```

while others can come out as

```
5
```

I don't know whether the issue is my script not ignoring empty lines or my CSV being written incorrectly, which is posted below.

```
Letter,Number
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
E,5
F,6
,7
,8
,9
,10
```

What's my issue here and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: Can't reproduce in modern PowerShell (5.0 here): https://puu.sh/qRd0w/f6a661a173.png

Comment: I think you are trying to solve a simple problem in a very weird way. Why don't you state what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you try the delimiter  `$L = ipcsv ln.csv -Delimiter ',' | Get-Random | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Letter`

Answer (score 0):

Your asking for a random object from your CSV, not a random letter. Since some of the lines are missing a letter, you might end up picking one that has an empty Letter-value.

If you want to pick any line **with** a letter, you need to filter the rows first to only pick from the ones with a value. Also, you sould avoid reading the same file twice, use a varible

```
#$csv = Import-CSV -Path ln.csv

$csv = @"
Letter,Number
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
E,5
F,6
,7
,8
,9
,10
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$L = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Letter } | Get-Random | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Letter
$N = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Number } | Get-Random | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Number

Write-Output $L
Write-Output $N
```

CSV migtht not be the best solution for this scenario. Ex. you could store these as arrays in the script, like:

```
$chars = [char[]](65..70) #A-F uppercase letters
$numbers = 1..10

$L = $chars | Get-Random
$N = $numbers | Get-Random

Write-Output $L
Write-Output $N
```

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Csv` turns each line into an object, with a property for each column.

Even though one or more property values may be empty, the *object* still exists, and `Get-Random` has no reason determine that an object with a certain property (such as `Letter`) having the value `""` (ie. an empty string), should not be picked.

You can fix this by expanding the property values first, then filter for empty values and then finally pick the random value from those that weren't empty:

```
$L = ipcsv ln.csv |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Letter |Where-Object {$_} |Get-Random
$N = ipcsv ln.csv |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Number |Where-Object {$_} |Get-Random
```